# Swagger UI not rendered :: AspNetCore

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-2.1, asp-net-core-spa-services

I wanted to have API Documentation with the use of NSwag.AspNetCore.11.18.7...package has been installed and necessary settings are set THEN executed **dotnet run**... WHEN I navigate to **http://localhost:5000/swagger** the API DOCS could not be displayed. Error message at the console are the following:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'swagger'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'swagger'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1719)
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (router.js:1684)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1719)
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (router.js:1684)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
    at eval (zone.js:858)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4736)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });


            services.AddSwagger();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });

            app.UseSwaggerUi();

            app.MapWhen(r => !r.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/swagger"), builder =>
            {
                builder.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                        name: "spa-fallback",
                        defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
                    );
                });
            });
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Ng2Webstorage, SessionStorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './components/menu/menu.component';
import { SettingComponent } from './components/setting/setting.component';
import { RouteGuardService } from './services/route-guard.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { LogoutComponent } from './components/logout/logout.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    SettingComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    Ng2Webstorage,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService], pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

      { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService] }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [RouteGuardService, UserService, SessionStorageService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the configuration for `services.AddSwagger();` and `app.UseSwaggerUi()`;

Also you can switch the nuget package to Swashbuckle.AspDotNet, and cofigure to the following:

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "NFC Demo Ci2", Version = "v1" });
});
```

Configure:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Catalogo de servicios");
});
```

I hope this has been useful for you

bye